# Git server on Raspberry Pi: pushing to the server freezes after "Total ..." line

Tags: git, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I recently had to do a total reinstall of my Pi's SD card with Raspbian (stretch). I had a Git server running on it and it worked flawlessly, pushing and pulling on the local network and remotely from work. Brilliant.

But then I installed Git again after reinstalling and setting up the Pi anew and it sort of works. No errors when installing Git, I can create repositories and clone them remotely, but when I try to push remotely it stalls after `Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)` and never finishes. The repository remains empty on the Pi.

As far as I know it's the same identical OS (Raspbian Stretch) and the setup is identical to what it used to be. The only change this time is that the HDD that I used to host my previous Git server on was a `vfat` type HDD which I then formatted to an empty `ext4` HDD. The drive is mounted by running `sudo mount -t ext4 -o defaults,users /dev/sda2 /mnt/NAME_OF_HDD`. The previous `vfat` partition was mounted through `fstab`.

**YES** I have tried to add the remote computer's `id_rsa.pub` key to `authorized_keys` and it works, but still freezes when pushing.

**YES** I have tried to reinstall git completely, still same behavior.

**NO** it's not because it's uploading large files. I tried to clone an empty repository, add a folder and then push. Still the same behavior.

Please help, I don't know what's wrong this time and the internet doesn't have many relevant answers to my problem..

Comment: Really? Nobody?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this was caused by a server directory ownership issue, most likely..
What I did at least was doing `sudo bash`, and then `chown -R pi /path/to/my/git/directory.git` on my server (pi) and it seemed to have fixed the issue.